# Gradle files directory in Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle, fastutil

After I pressed option 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' in Android Studio, where are these downloaded files (e.g. fastutil-7.2.0.jar) placed in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the exact location may vary depending on your installation, here are a few steps to have Android Studio show you the directory with the downloaded files:

- Scroll to the "External libraries" section in the lower half of the Project file tree
- Click a library (e.g. `Gradle: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2@aar`)
- Right-click a `jar` file (`classes.jar` in the above example)
- Choose "Show in Explorer" from the context menu
- Navigate up to see the other library files